# Unix - Find patterns in file, copy into another file

Tags: unix, awk, grep, find

I have spent some time considering how to tackle this but i'm not sure and my use of unix is fairly limited so far.

I have a text file, lets give it a name "Text.txt", which contains lots of information. Let's say it contains:

```
SomethingA: aValue
SomethingB: bValue
SomethingC: cValue
SomethingD: dValue
SomethingD: anotherDValueThisTime
SomethingA: aValueToIgnore
```

I want to search through "Text.txt", and find some values, then put the values in a new file, output.txt.

This gets a little bit more tricky tough, as what I am trying to do is get the first value of somethingA, and then every SomethingD value which occurs.

So the output in "output.txt" should be:

```
aValue
dValue
anotherDValue
```

The second "SomethingA" value wants to be ignored as this is not the first "SomethingA" value.

I imagine the logic to be something like:
Find SomethingA > output.txt
Find ALL SomethingD's >> output.txt

But I just can't quite get it.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you care if the somethingD is before the somethingA in the input file?

Comment: The ordering isn't a problem. So long as all of the SomethingD's are together, it doesn't matter if somethingA comes at the start or at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is ideal

```
awk '/^SomethingA/ && ! a++ || /^SomethingD/ { print $2 }' FS=: text.txt > output.txt
```

This is a little sloppy, but you can be more precise with:

```
awk '$1 == "SomethingA" && ! a++ || $1 == "SomethingD" { print $2 }' FS=: text.txt > output.txt
```

Unfortunately, that requires a fixed string for the keys.  If you want a regex, you can do:

```
awk 'match($1, "pattern") && ...
```

Comment: You have saved me a lot of head banging. Thanks for the solution, I will spend some time reading into awk. This solution actually worked perfectly, first time. Thankyou. I just saw your second answer/improvement. I only need a fixed string for the keys as they will all be the same. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you want to match a field against a regex in awk, you can use `$1 ~ /pattern/ { stuff }` or `$1 !~ /pattern/ { stuff }`.

Comment: @Stobor Thanks, that is definitely more appropriate.  I plead temporary amnesia.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -m 1 somethingA inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt
grep somethingD inputfile.txt >>outputfile.txt
```

`grep` option `-m` sets the maximum number of matches you want to get.

`>>` appends to a file rather than overwriting it like `>` does.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the `grep` command with the `-o` options. It works like this:

```
grep -o -e 'pattern1' -e 'pattern2' /tmp/1 >> /tmp/2
```